# Could not uninstall twilio, permission denied

Tags: python

I started off with getting the error message: 
ImportError: No module named twilio.rest

I had installed twilio using sudo easy_install twilio and then uninstalled using sudo pip uninstall twilio to try and fix this:

import twilio
-bash: import: command not found

Now I'm getting this error

OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twilio-6.8.4.dist-info/DESCRIPTION.rst'

Any ideas what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run like this :

```
sudo pip install twilio
```

that's it